# Xcode 10 won't create a developer signing certificate, get OSStatus error -2147416032

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-certificate, osstatus

I'm a newbie to Xcode 10 and tried to create a stickers app using Automatic Signing and logged in with a free appleID account.  In the app target, the status for the certificate says that it couldn't be completed (OSStatus error -2147416032.) and no provisioning profiles were found for my new app.

I went to preferences -> Accounts -> Manage Certificates and have no certificates.  I tried to create an "iOS Developer certificate" and got the error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -2147416032.)"

I also used the "security find-identity -v -p codesignin" cmd in terminal and got the result " 0 valid identities found".

Shouldn't Xcode automatically create a certificate?  Or do I need to create one myself.  I tried to request one through Keychain using the Certificate Assistant but I couldn't find the area to upload it to developer.apple.com - it said I needed to be a member of the developer program to manage certificates.

Xcode 10.3,
macOS 10.13.6

Comment: I'm getting this too. Maybe it's Apple dev pay wall in operation?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue on my High Sierra 10.13.6.
I have two versions of Xcode (10.2 and 10.1) installed on my Mac and this problem occured when using Xcode 10.2.
I tried to create the certificate with Xcode 10.1 and it worked perfectly.
I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Creating ios development certificate via developer center, downloading it (ios_development.cer) and installing into my Keychain has fixed this for me.